# Turbolinks: How to stop running functions when you leave the page?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks

In my Rails `5.2.2` app I am using [Turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks).

I have discovered that when I leave a page, the functions that were started continues.

I have organised my functions below a `return` statement that checks the body class. In my example below, if the body class is not `foobar` the functions below do not run.

```js
// assets/javascripts/pages/foobar.js

var goLoop;

$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
  if (!$("body").hasClass("foobar")) {
    return;
  }
  return goLoop();
});

goLoop = function() {
  return setTimeout((function() {
    console.log("Hello");
    return goLoop();
  }), 1000);
};
```

1. First time I visit the page, the `goLoop` function is triggered.
2. When I follow a link away from the page, the function runs. If I had not used Turbolinks, this would not have happened.
3. If I follow another link back to the page, the function is triggered again, so now it runs twice.

How can I avoid this, without disabling Turbolinks?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `turbolinks:before-cache` to teardown your timeout using `clearTimeout`. You will need to keep a reference of the current timeout ID. So your solution might look like:

```
var goLoop;
var timeout;

$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
  if (!$("body").hasClass("foobar")) {
    return;
  }
  return goLoop();
});

goLoop = function() {
  return timeout = setTimeout((function() {
    console.log("Hello");
    return goLoop();
  }), 1000);
};

$(document).on("turbolinks:before-render", function() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PageVisibilityAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) to see is current page active or not.

and for the loop issue, you should check whether it's exist or not then run timeout function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The PageVisibilityAPI is very interesting, so I have implemented that. But I'll keep the question open a bit longer, since what I am really looking for is how to avoid functions running after leaving the page.

Comment: @JohnSmith1976 it's better to use setInterval instead of two nested timeout then you you should listen on visibilitychange then you can stop your loop with clearInterval function